# Update data netbeans

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have a problem when updating data with NetBeans. When I update without changing the id, the error message appears key duplicate '10' for 'primary'

```
SQL = "update sumber set nama_sumber=?, alamat_sumber=?, kapasitas_sumber=? WHERE id_sumber='"+kodegudang+"'";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
ps.setString(1, txt_id.getText());
ps.setString(2, txt_nama.getText());
ps.setString(3, txt_alamat.getText());
ps.setString(4, kapasitasdos.getText());
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sumber Air berhasil Diedit");

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Please describe in detail what you are having issues with and provide the error / exception you are getting. What's clearly an issue is that you have three placeholders in your prepared statement, yet you try to fill four.

Comment: this error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '10' for key 'PRIMARY'. and my id_sumber set primary key

Answer (score 0):

All the primary key values in a table must be different. I'm guessing that you already have a row with `nama_sumber = 10` (or whatever the primary key is). You can check that by connecting to the database directly and running `select * from sumber`.